# Change reset password window

Tags: windows, active-directory

How can I change the Reset Password window in login side to different window?
If someone will click to Reset Password then my window would appear where users can change their password after they answered to security questions.
[Login page with Reset password text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrsMv.png)

I saw this method in my school but with Windows 7. I want to do this in Windows 10.
Thank you in advance the responses. :)

Answer (score 1):

This capability is not a functionality that can be configured in Windows out of the box.

Your school probably was using [Forefront Identity Manager](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forefront_Identity_Manager) or the newer [Microsoft Identity Manager.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/microsoft-identity-manager)

There are other 3rd party applications available to implement similar functionality. All of which are designed for the enterprise and I’m not aware of any offering that is free.

This can also be accomplished by designing a custom [credential provider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthN/credential-providers-in-windows). The implementation is difficult and has some security risks. This is not something that can be done without extensive knowledge in several different areas.

Comment: Well hmm, I use https://www.univention.com/ as AD so hmm I don't know. What I know is that when I click to Reset password on the school PC then not the Reset Password Wizard will appear, instead their application where I need to give my username and after answer two questions and if I answer correctly then I can change the password. But hmm it seems that it is not enough only change the exe file or where is the password reset wizard. Indeed it is a complicated process.